# How to get value (String) from String (html code)

Tags: java, http, substring

```
 <span class="dane_anonsu_wyroznij">Wiek: </span> <span class="dane_anonsu_value">28 lat</span></li> <li><span class="dane_anonsu_wyroznij">Waga: </span> <span class="dane_anonsu_value">69 kg</span></li> 
    <li><span class="dane_anonsu_wyroznij">Wzrost: </span> <span class="dane_anonsu_value">170 cm</span></li>  
    <li><span class="dane_anonsu_wyroznij">Biust: </span> <span class="dane_anonsu_value">3   </span></li>   
    <li><span class="dane_anonsu_wyroznij">Języki: </span> <span class="dane_anonsu_value">   angielski,        </span></li>  
    <li> alt="Cennik:"/><span class="dane_anonsu_tytul">Cennik</span> </li> 
    <li><span class="dane_anonsu_fiolet dane_anonsu_wyroznij dane_anonsu_tytul">1 godz.:</span> <span class="dane_anonsu_fiolet dane_anonsu_tytul">***150 zł***</span></li>  
    <li><span class="dane_anonsu_wyroznij">15 min.:</span> <span class="dane_anonsu_value">***100*** zł </span></li>  
    <li><span class="dane_anonsu_wyroznij">30 min.:</span> <span class="dane_anonsu_value">***150 zł*** </span></li>  
    <li><span class="dane_anonsu_wyroznij">Całą noc:</span> <span class="dane_anonsu_value">***1200 zł*** </span></li>     
    <li><span class="dane_anonsu_tytul">Czas pracy:</span> </li>   
    <li><span class="dane_anonsu_wyroznij">pn. - pt.:</span> <span>od 8 do 22</span></li>    
    <li><span class="dane_anonsu_wyroznij">sobota:</span> <span>od 8 do 22</span></li>  
    <li><span class="dane_anonsu_wyroznij">niedziela:</span> <span>od 8 do 22</span></li>  </ul> 
    </div> <!--<div class="clear">&nbsp; </div> --> </div>
```

this is the page code, I have to take four values i.e. prices, do you have any idea ? beyond calculating characters and making it a substring

Comment: Use an arbitrary html parser, maybe [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/)...

Comment: Not every one here is familiar with zloty. Help yourself by making your question easier to read: format the code properly and indicate exactly what field(s) you want to extract, with the correct name in the code AND in the question

Comment: Can you edit with more code aside your HTML?

Comment: Instead of using an arbitrary html parser, you could also use a regular expression. It's probably sufficient for your needs.

Comment: @Quaffel - parsing HTML with regular expressions is not a habit we want to teach new programmers. It's the wrong thing to do except if the HTML is completely within your own control and you know it has no recursive structures and is not likely to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex is a solution. It is not the best solution. But it is an option for your choice.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "class=\"dane_anonsu_wyroznij\">Wiek: </span> <span class=\"dane_anonsu_value\">28 lat</span></li> <li><span class=\"dane_anonsu_wyroznij\">Waga: </span> <span class=\"dane_anonsu_value\">69 kg</span></li> \n"
                + "<li><span class=\"dane_anonsu_wyroznij\">Wzrost: </span> <span class=\"dane_anonsu_value\">170 cm</span></li>  \n"
                + "<li><span class=\"dane_anonsu_wyroznij\">Biust: </span> <span class=\"dane_anonsu_value\">3   </span></li>   \n"
                + "<li><span class=\"dane_anonsu_wyroznij\">Języki: </span> <span class=\"dane_anonsu_value\">   angielski,        </span></li>  \n"
                + "<li> alt=\"Cennik:\"/><span class=\"dane_anonsu_tytul\">Cennik</span> </li> \n"
                + "<li><span class=\"dane_anonsu_fiolet dane_anonsu_wyroznij dane_anonsu_tytul\">1 godz.:</span> <span class=\"dane_anonsu_fiolet dane_anonsu_tytul\">***150 zł***</span></li>  \n"
                + "<li><span class=\"dane_anonsu_wyroznij\">15 min.:</span> <span class=\"dane_anonsu_value\">***100*** zł </span></li>  \n"
                + "<li><span class=\"dane_anonsu_wyroznij\">30 min.:</span> <span class=\"dane_anonsu_value\">***150 zł*** </span></li>  \n"
                + "<li><span class=\"dane_anonsu_wyroznij\">Całą noc:</span> <span class=\"dane_anonsu_value\">***1200 zł*** </span></li>     \n"
                + "<li><span class=\"dane_anonsu_tytul\">Czas pracy:</span> </li>   \n"
                + "<li><span class=\"dane_anonsu_wyroznij\">pn. - pt.:</span> <span>od 8 do 22</span></li>    \n"
                + "<li><span class=\"dane_anonsu_wyroznij\">sobota:</span> <span>od 8 do 22</span></li>  \n"
                + "<li><span class=\"dane_anonsu_wyroznij\">niedziela:</span> <span>od 8 do 22</span></li>  </ul> \n"
                + "</div> <!--<div class=\"clear\">&nbsp; </div> --> </div>  ";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern
                .compile(">([^<]+)</")
                .matcher(html);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found: " + matcher.group(1));
        }
```

For string processing, Regex is good. But for HTML processing, a HTML parser could be the better.